# Hide page numbers in jquery paginate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pagination

I am using a jquery function to paginate items in my website page.

This is the function:

```
(function($) {
        var pagify = {
            items: {},
            container: null,
            totalPages: 1,
            perPage: 3,
            currentPage: 0,
            createNavigation: function() {
                this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.items.length / this.perPage);

                $('.pagination', this.container.parent()).remove();
                var pagination = $('<div class="pagination"></div>').append('<a class="nav prev disabled" data-next="false"><</a>');

                for (var i = 0; i < this.totalPages; i++) {
                    var pageElClass = "page";
                    if (!i)
                        pageElClass = "page current";
                    var pageEl = '<a class="' + pageElClass + '" data-page="' + (
                    i + 1) + '">' + (
                    i + 1) + "</a>";
                    pagination.append(pageEl);
                }
                pagination.append('<a class="nav next" data-next="true">></a>');

                this.container.after(pagination);

                var that = this;
                $("body").off("click", ".nav");
                this.navigator = $("body").on("click", ".nav", function() {
                    var el = $(this);
                    that.navigate(el.data("next"));
                });

                $("body").off("click", ".page");
                this.pageNavigator = $("body").on("click", ".page", function() {
                    var el = $(this);
                    that.goToPage(el.data("page"));
                });
            },
            navigate: function(next) {
                // default perPage to 5
                if (isNaN(next) || next === undefined) {
                    next = true;
                }
                $(".pagination .nav").removeClass("disabled");
                if (next) {
                    this.currentPage++;
                    if (this.currentPage > (this.totalPages - 1))
                        this.currentPage = (this.totalPages - 1);
                    if (this.currentPage == (this.totalPages - 1))
                        $(".pagination .nav.next").addClass("disabled");
                    }
                else {
                    this.currentPage--;
                    if (this.currentPage < 0)
                        this.currentPage = 0;
                    if (this.currentPage == 0)
                        $(".pagination .nav.prev").addClass("disabled");
                    }

                this.showItems();
            },
            updateNavigation: function() {

                var pages = $(".pagination .page");
                pages.removeClass("current");
                $('.pagination .page[data-page="' + (
                this.currentPage + 1) + '"]').addClass("current");
            },
            goToPage: function(page) {

                this.currentPage = page - 1;

                $(".pagination .nav").removeClass("disabled");
                if (this.currentPage == (this.totalPages - 1))
                    $(".pagination .nav.next").addClass("disabled");

                if (this.currentPage == 0)
                    $(".pagination .nav.prev").addClass("disabled");
                this.showItems();
            },
            showItems: function() {
                this.items.hide();
                var base = this.perPage * this.currentPage;
                this.items.slice(base, base + this.perPage).show();

                this.updateNavigation();
            },
            init: function(container, items, perPage) {
                this.container = container;
                this.currentPage = 0;
                this.totalPages = 1;
                this.perPage = perPage;
                this.items = items;
                this.createNavigation();
                this.showItems();
            }
        };

        // stuff it all into a jQuery method!
        $.fn.pagify = function(perPage, itemSelector) {
            var el = $(this);
            var items = $(itemSelector, el);

            // default perPage to 5
            if (isNaN(perPage) || perPage === undefined) {
                perPage = 3;
            }

            // don't fire if fewer items than perPage
            if (items.length <= perPage) {
                return true;
            }

            pagify.init(el, items, perPage);
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $(".ff-stream-wrapper").pagify(8, ".ff-item");
```

now I have many pages (33 pages). In page numbers I want to only show first 5 page numbers and the last one, other pages shown if are close to current page, for example if I go to page 2, number 6 apears.

**current view of page numbers:**

[image: current view of page numbers]

**What I want to do:**

[image]

Comment: Could you use [jQuery Pagination](https://codeload.github.com/infusion/jQuery-Paging/legacy.zip/v1.2.0) ?

Comment: I already used this one, if you suggest me to use that please explain me why otherwise please give me the solution for current plugin.

Comment: If you had already tried that, you should have said so, AND explained why it did not do what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider referencing the implementation of the pageRange option: https://pagination.js.org/docs/index.html#pageRange

in https://github.com/superRaytin/paginationjs/blob/master/src/pagination.js